# Can I manipulate a directory stream obtained with opendir()?

Tags: c, linux, opendir

The function `opendir()` returns a pointer to a directory stream `DIR *`, which apparently is an opaque data type. The implementation is hidden.

The [libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-a-Directory.html) states that you should not allocate a `DIR` object yourself and let the directory functions handle the allocation.

Is there any way to manipulate a directory stream after obtaining it with `opendir()` and before passing it to, for example, `readdir()`?

I basically want to overload  `opendir()` with `LD_PRELOAD` to return a manipulated directory stream, which is used by `readdir()`.

Comment: Maybe you could hijack `readdir` and make it return what you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to look at what the `LD_PRELOAD` [`sortdir`](ftp://ftp.uhulinux.hu/pub/sources/sortdir/sortdir-0.6.tar.gz)  does as it sorts the directory entries before giving them to the program although what you might want to do might be something other than sorting.

`sortdir` replaces `opendir`, `readdir`, `readdir64`, and `closedir` and being only 197 lines of code, it would serve you well to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible, or at least not possible in any sort of portable fashion.  As you said the `DIR*` type is an opaque pointer.  The `DIR` file is defined in an implementation specific fashion in a file you don't have access to.

In order to manipulate the returned `DIR` value you'd have to create a `struct` of similar structure which contains the manipulated values.  Implementations are free to vary the definition of `DIR` or change it without warning (it is opaque after all).  So any implementation you added would be fragile at best.

Comment: Indeed, this is not possible in any portable fashion, i.e. any solution would be inherently tied to the particular `opendir`/`readdir` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you want to manipulate the directory entries, e.g. change file names or add dummy entries. You can do it like that.

Overload `opendir()`, within it really open the directory with "real" `opendir()`, immediately read all directory entries, with "real" `readdir()`, modify what's necessary, store the modified version in a global variable and return unmodified `DIR *`. Then in the overloaded `readdir()` you treat passed `DIR *` as your own opaque value (e.g. key in a map) and simply sequentially return previously prepared entries.

Here's a nasty proof of concept (nasty because I skipped the boring part like error checking, resource closing, memory freeing, thread safety, etc.):

opendir_wrap.cpp -> opendir_wrap.so:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <list>

extern "C" {

static std::map<DIR *, std::list<struct dirent*> > MAP;

typedef DIR *(*OPEN_T)(const char *name);
typedef struct dirent *(*READ_T)(DIR *dirp);
static OPEN_T real_opendir = NULL;
static READ_T real_readdir = NULL;

DIR *opendir(const char *name)
{
    void *handle = dlopen("/lib/libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!real_opendir) real_opendir = (OPEN_T) dlsym(handle, "opendir");
    if (!real_readdir) real_readdir = (READ_T) dlsym(handle, "readdir");

    DIR *dirp = real_opendir(name);
    struct dirent *entry = NULL;
    while (entry = real_readdir(dirp))
    {
        MAP[dirp].push_back(entry);
    }
    MAP[dirp].push_back(NULL);

    // your modifications here
    struct dirent *joke = new struct dirent;
    sprintf(joke->d_name, "JOKE!");
    MAP[dirp].push_front(joke);

    return dirp;
}

struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp)
{
    struct dirent *entry = MAP[dirp].front();
    MAP[dirp].pop_front();
    return entry;
}

} // extern "C"
```

opedir_use.c -> opendir_use:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct dirent *entry = NULL;
    DIR *dirp = opendir(".");
    printf("dirp = %p\n", dirp);
    while (entry = readdir(dirp))
    {
        printf("entry->d_name = %s\n", entry->d_name);
    }
}
```

Now compile:

```
$ gcc -fpic -shared -ldl -lstdc++ -o ./opendir_wrap.so ./opendir_wrap.cpp
$ gcc opendir_use.c -o opendir_use
```

Run normally:

```
$ ./opendir_use 
dirp = 0x9fd3008
entry->d_name = opendir_wrap.so
entry->d_name = opendir_use
entry->d_name = opendir_use.c
entry->d_name = opendir_wrap.cpp
entry->d_name = ..
entry->d_name = .
```

Run with the wrapper:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/opendir_wrap.so ./opendir_use
dirp = 0x95374b8
entry->d_name = JOKE!
entry->d_name = opendir_wrap.so
entry->d_name = opendir_use
entry->d_name = opendir_use.c
entry->d_name = opendir_wrap.cpp
entry->d_name = ..
entry->d_name = .
```