# What happens in C function readdir() from dirent.h?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I'm doing a school assignment and the task at hand is to count the files and folders recursively. I use the readdir() function, it seems to iterate through the directory I gave it.

```
int listdir(const char *path) 
{
  struct dirent *entry;
  DIR *dp;

  dp = opendir(path);
  if (dp == NULL) 
  {
    perror("opendir");
    return -1;
  }

  while((entry = readdir(dp)))
    puts(entry->d_name);

  closedir(dp);
  return 0;
}
```

I want to see the "something++;" step of this function, there should be one, right? All I can find is this line in glibc's dirent/dirent.h

```
extern struct dirent *readdir (DIR *__dirp) __nonnull ((1));
```

and

```
struct dirent *
__readdir (DIR *dirp)
{
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return NULL;
}
weak_alias (__readdir, readdir)
```

in dirent/readdir.c

Where does the iteration happen?

Maybe a duplicate of [How readdir function is working inside while loop in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405086/how-readdir-function-is-working-inside-while-loop-in-c)

I tried to grep through glibc source code for readdir - didn't find, searched the Internet - didn't find, although some say there is an obsolete linux system call also called readdir.

There is also this

> "
> The readdir() function returns a pointer to a dirent structure
> representing the next directory entry in the directory stream
> pointed to by dirp.  It returns NULL on reaching the end of the
> directory stream or if an error occurred."

and this

> "
> The  order in which filenames are read by successive calls to readdir()
> depends on the filesystem implementation; it is unlikely that the names
> will be sorted in any fashion."

in man readdir .

From this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344137/12847376
I assume OS can hijack functions with LD_PRELOAD, I see no such variable in my default shell. And too many hits in the Debian source search.

I also grepped through the Linux kernel for LD_PRELOAD and readdir and got too many results on the syscall.

Comment: Here is the source code of interest: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/readdir.c Not sure why you want to see it though, the implementation may differ, the important thing is the documented behavior.

Comment: Isn't there a 'write beyond end of buffer' bug in the line `dp->d_name[sizeof dp->d_name] = '\0';`?  It probably isn't used very often because GLibC defines `_DIRENT_HAVE_D_RECLEN`, but …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: There's a comment above that line that notes it's intentionally clobbering the next byte, and knows it's safe because it's populating an array one element at a time, and the byte clobbered is always in the next entry, that won't be used until the calling code is done with the current entry. Guessing the allocation is padded by a byte to deal with that somewhere else to make the last overwrite safe (or it's just relying on there being an extra byte in the real allocation, which is terrible, but system libs are allowed to be terrible).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Hmmm…ugh!  But yes, there is a comment.  Ugh!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Looking around, AFAICT, everyone but Oracle has a `d_reclen` in the struct (so that overrun code isn't used) and Oracle's `struct dirent` is ridiculously barebones (just the inode number and the fixed length name array). They probably overspecialized for that implementation to avoid needing to figure out adjust their allocation to include the extra byte per struct for a terminator (because `getdents` itself will use the whole array without terminating, but an efficient `readdir` needs the terminator to avoid unnecessary copies).

Comment: That code path is also kind of nasty in that it has to issue a `getdents` system call per entry, rather than issuing a single `getdents` to fill a whole buffer with multiple entries in a single call, and it's all because of that buffer overwrite (if it wasn't overwriting, it could fetch in bulk in a single syscall, then serve multiple `readdir`s without jumping back to the kernel, improving efficiency, but the cheap overwrite hack prevents them from being able to do that, just in case a name is exactly large enough to fill the buffer).

Comment: Presumably they felt this was worth it to avoid needing to increase the size of the allocation by `alignof(struct dirent)` or whatever (they couldn't just allocate one extra byte per struct, as they'd end up misaligning `d_ino`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger — thanks for the extra information.  I sometimes wish POSIX was a little less minimalistic in what it specifies, but it does try to avoid breaking existing systems, and presumably there was enough prior art without `d_reclen` that they felt they couldn't legislate that it must be present.

Comment: It would be trivial to use the POSIX [nftw()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) function for this.  I just don't understand why people insist on using the idiotic opendir()/readdir()/closedir() interface, when nftw(), [scandir()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html), and [glob()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) are available in the Linux standard C library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where does the iteration happen?

On Linux, it happens [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/readdir.c;h=c9a04dc16081906da6b48ae49d20860bffb5e916;hb=HEAD#l26). As you can see, the code repeatedly calls [getdents](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) (system call) to obtain a set of entries from the kernel, and "advances" the `dp` by updating `dirp->offset`, etc.

```
  24 /* Read a directory entry from DIRP.  */
  25 struct dirent *
  26 __readdir_unlocked (DIR *dirp)
  27 {
  28   struct dirent *dp;
  29   int saved_errno = errno;
  30 
  31   if (dirp->offset >= dirp->size)
  32     {
  33       /* We've emptied out our buffer.  Refill it.  */
  34 
  35       size_t maxread = dirp->allocation;
  36       ssize_t bytes;
  37 
  38       bytes = __getdents (dirp->fd, dirp->data, maxread);
  39       if (bytes <= 0)
  40         {
  41           /* Linux may fail with ENOENT on some file systems if the
  42              directory inode is marked as dead (deleted).  POSIX
  43              treats this as a regular end-of-directory condition, so
  44              do not set errno in that case, to indicate success.  */
  45           if (bytes == 0 || errno == ENOENT)
  46             __set_errno (saved_errno);
  47           return NULL;
  48         }
  49       dirp->size = (size_t) bytes;
  50 
  51       /* Reset the offset into the buffer.  */
  52       dirp->offset = 0;
  53     }
  54 
  55   dp = (struct dirent *) &dirp->data[dirp->offset];
  56   dirp->offset += dp->d_reclen;
  57   dirp->filepos = dp->d_off;
  58 
  59   return dp;
  60 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  I have implemented something similar to this for another language's core library, so I can say there is not a `++something`.  The reason for that, is that the structures returned by the operating system do not have a consistent size.  The structure is something *like* the following:

```
struct dirent {
    long           d_ino;
    off_t          d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    char           d_type;
    char           d_name[];
};
```

You pass a buffer to the system call (I used `getdents64`), and it fills it in with a bunch of these dirent structures.  That `d_name[]` does not have an officially known size. The size of the entire structure is defined by that `d_reclen` member of the struct.

In memory, you could have many `struct dirent` like this:

```
[0]                    [1]                                           [2]
44,0,24,DT_REG,"a.txt",41,0,47,DT_DIR,"a_really_long_directory_name",...
```

Here is a rough translation of how it works:

```
uint8_t buf[BUFLEN];
long n = getdents64(dfd, buf, BUFLEN);
if (n < 0) {
    // error
}

// buf now holds dirent structs

struct dirent* d = buf;
int i = 0;
for (; i < res; i += d->d_reclen) { // <<<< this is the trick
     d = &buf[i];
     // do something with the d
}
```

Notice the way we increment `i`.  Since the `d_name` member does not have an official size, we cannot just say `struct dirent d[COUNT];`.  We don't know how big each struct will be.

Comment: Is there any way to force `getdents64` to only read one structure per call?

Comment: @HoseinRahnama No.  Since the struct itself is flexible, it is just going to stupidly fill your buffer.  The first struct could be 80 bytes, or it could be 1000 bytes.  You could try using a smaller buffer if that is what your are worried about.  The syscall should return `EINVAL` if your buffer is not big enough to store one entry.  So, you could use `malloc` for a smaller buffer and `realloc` bigger if you get `EINVAL`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice tips. Where can I read the exact implementation of `readdir`?

Comment: @HoseinRahnama Employed Russian's answer actually has the glibc implementation of  `readdir` copied into it if you want to see it.  Notice that it is really just a thin wrapper around `__getdents` which, itself, is a thin wrapper around the `getdents64` syscall.  If you are looking for the implementation of `getdents64`, you will have to peek into the kernel code.